# Insert a range of numbers in Sublime Text 2

Tags: vim, sublime-text-2

Is there a way to insert a range of numbers in Sublime Text 2? I have been unable to find a command or plugin, and I have to insert sequences like this semi-frequently. I'm looking for something akin to `:put =range(11,15)` in Vim, which would print

```
11
12
13
14
15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a package (in the package manager) called "Insert Nums." Select all the regions into which you wish to place numbers, run the command (CTRL-OPT-n on my Mac CTRL-Alt-n for Win/*NIX) and you'll be able to insert numbers. The package allows you to specify the start, step, and number padding.

Answer (score 5):

The [Text Pastry package](https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry) support the syntax from 'Insert Nums', but adds extra features, such as inserting a sequence of words and presets for 1-indexed and 0-indexed number generators.

Comment: Also works in sublime text 3